# Ninject: Resolve dependency by name only

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2

I have a WPF view\view-model binding pattern where I would like to resolve dependencies from Ninject by name only, rather than by type or type+name. I want to bind my view-models by name with Ninject, and then refer to the view-models in views by this name for view injection (via Caliburn.Micro).

I realize that in practice multiple types could be registered against the same name, but I want a convention type pattern and am willing to live with this case. I only need to resolve to "object" for WPF binding to work.

For instance, is there some way I can:

- Retrieve all bindings regardless of what types they are registered against.
- Probe for a binding with the appropriate name.
- Create an instance via the binding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way is to bind them as object

```
kernel.Bind<object>().To<MyClass>().Named("A")
kernel.Get<object>("A");
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work nicely in a convention based binding pattern I am working on.